# WPF DispatcherTimer check 5 seconds for external program

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, timer

How would I use `DispatcherTimer` to check every 5 seconds to see if external program is running. If it is running then `button1` will be disabled.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`Process.GetProcessesByName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessesbyname.aspx) to check to see if a given process is running.  When this returns results, disable your button.

```
var timer = new DispatcherTimer
            {
                 Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)
            };
timer.Tick += (o,e) =>
            this.button1.IsEnabled =
                 !Process.GetProcessesByName("TheExternalProgramName").Any();
timer.Start();
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm a newbie. How would I code the DispatcherTimer to check every 5 seconds? Any examples would be be great.